# code first -The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string

Tags: exception, deployment, ef-code-first, connection-string

I wrote a windows form solution with 2 layers; one is DataAccess and the other is windows form. 
I use Code first. If DataAccess Layer runs in the application console, there is no problem with the db. Create the schema and insert the data.

However, when I run the solution with Windows Form as the initial project and refer to DataAccess as a dll, I cannot build the database. It throws an exception.

I think that the app.config file is the problem, but if I copy the app.config file of DataAccess project to the windows form, it does not resolve the problem.

**the config file of DataAcces layer:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**the exception:**

```
"first exception for 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' in     EntityFramework.dll

Aditional Information: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."
```

**Inner Exception:**

```
{"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."}
```

Comment: after a long deep search, i found that solution was "clean the solution", after that, all run normally

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be due to Error in connection string 
or in my case it was that
SQL server service was not running 
manually start the SQL service through SQL SERVER COnfiguration Manager

Answer (score 0):

after a long deep search, i found that solution was "clean the solution".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: but, that was the solution. go to Visual Studio and click on "Build"/"Clean  Solution"